# How to display text from a website on UILabel?

Tags: html, swift, uilabel

I want to display some text from a website on my label.
If something changes in the website, every time my label should get updated.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var lanelView: UILabel!
        let url = NSURL(string: "the webiste")
```

If something in the website says "cool", I want my label to do

```
label.text = "cool"
```

Comment: You will need to load the website and parse the html for the field that you are trying to track. Can you provide more information on exactly what you are trying to parse for? Also, posting more complete code will be helpful for making an answer. 
Are you having trouble loading the URL, or just parsing the response?

Comment: This question is too broad.  How is the text stored on the web.  Is it a value from an API?  An HTML string?  There are too many possible ways to answer this question.

Comment: yes i am sorry about this its fourth app that i am trying to create and its hard to me to explain .. so lets try like this : there is a website that connect with a server that give information when the server is down there will be text in the website that will say the server is down right now and when the server is working will say the server on. so i want do app that what ever the server say that its type it in my label so my label will be connected with this website. i hope that i did explain it right